# javascript reduce method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const productsg = [ { product: 'banana', price: 3 }, { product: 'mango', price: 6 }, { product: 'potato', price: ' ' }, { product: 'avocado', price: 8 }, { product: 'coffee', price: 10 }, { product: 'tea', price: '' }, ]
```

Find the sum of price of products using only reduce reduce(callback))

```
const num=productsg.reduce((acc,a)=>{

    if(typeof a.price=='number'){
        console.log(a.price,acc);
        return acc+a.pricex
    }
},0)
```

give undefined

pls help

Comment: Because if the price isn’t a number, the callback doesn’t return anything.

Answer (score 2):

You need to always return the accumulator.

```
const num=productsg.reduce((acc,a)=>{

    if(typeof a.price=='number'){
        console.log(a.price,acc);
        return acc+a.pricex
    }
    return acc; 
},0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your reduce using `Number`

if it's not a valid number it returns 0

```js
const productsg = [ { product: 'banana', price: 3 }, { product: 'mango', price: 6 }, { product: 'potato', price: ' ' }, { product: 'avocado', price: 8 }, { product: 'coffee', price: 10 }, { product: 'tea', price: '' }, ]


const num=productsg.reduce((acc,a)=> acc + Number(a.price),0)

console.log(num)
```